# SQL - Decimals in varchar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is this query pulling `99.73` when I have specified `cast(measure_rate as decimal)= 100`?

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zip_code ORDER BY cast(measure_rate as decimal) DESC) AS rn
   FROM AmbulatoryMeasures
   where measure_rate != 'n/a'
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
and cast(measure_rate as decimal) = 100
```

The result of the `measure_rate` column -

```
100
99.73
100
100
```

The data type of the `measure_rate` column is a varchar(50).

I would not expect `99.73` value in the result set because of the where clause.

Comment: The better questions is why are you using a `varchar` to store a numerical value?  99.73 is not > 100, but it is in your data.

Comment: `DECIMAL` with no precision or scale defaults to `DECIMAL(18, 0)`, which is almost certainly not what you want here. Even if it was, it pays to be explicit.

Comment: You have not specified decimal precision and scale - by default it is (38,0), what means that your values are rounded to integer. Use `cast(measure_rate as decimal(38, 5))` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify precision, while casting to DECIMAL. 
Consider following two snippets.

```
    --Your situation - no precision 
        DECLARE @test AS TABLE(MYVALUE VARCHAR(50));
        INSERT INTO @test
               SELECT '99.73';
        SELECT myvalue, 
               CAST(myvalue AS DECIMAL)
        FROM @test
        WHERE CAST(myvalue AS DECIMAL) = 100;

--Casting with precision         
        DECLARE @test2 AS TABLE(MYVALUE VARCHAR(50));
        INSERT INTO @test2
               SELECT '99.73';
        SELECT myvalue, 
               CAST(myvalue AS DECIMAL(10,2))
        FROM @test2
```

The result is shown in the picture below. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default number of decimals is `0`. If you specify the decimal with precision and scale you get the correct result you are after:

`SELECT CAST('99.73' AS DECIMAL(18,2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you cast 99.73 to DECIMAL you get 100 so the result is expected, to consider the decimal part do something like this for 2 decimals precision

```
 CAST(measure_rate AS DECIMAL(38, 2))
```

(38 for precision is just an example, select a number that suits your data better)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a scale or precision for your `decimal` so the default is used. This likely means that the scale is set to 0 so `'99.73'` is cast to `100` due to rounding.

If you change your data type of your column in your table from a `varchar` to`decimal` with an appropriate scale and precision this won't happen. This is just one reason why choosing the wrong data type is a bad decision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define precision of decimal  number of digits  and number oof decimal placies 
you can use

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zip_code ORDER BY cast(measure_rate as decimal) DESC) AS rn
   FROM AmbulatoryMeasures
   where measure_rate != 'n/a'
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
and cast(measure_rate as decimal(16,2)) = 100
```